# client can't parse JSon, what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, arrays, node.js

Server side code as:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({ "a": "128", "b": "7" });   
});
```

server side is receiving correctly, printed as:

```
{ '{"type":"type","age":32,"married":false}': '' }
```

the client side as :

```
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: self.serverURI,
                    data: JSON.stringify(self.gen_data()),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) 
                    {
                             //alert(result);
                             alert(JSON.parse(result));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
                    {
                            console.log(xhr);
                    }
                });

    self.gen_data=function()
    {   //create request data
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.type = "type";
        obj.age  = 32;
        obj.married = false;
        return obj;
    }
```

after getting response from server

```
 alert(result);
```

showed

```
[object object]
```

so, I try to parse

```
alert(JSON.parse(result));
```

and no alert pop up, so assuming it could not parse it.
I wanted to exchange JSon data containing arrays inside, but these simple test is not working.

what is the problem?  can anyone explain to me?

Thanks!

Comment: you need  some JDother :))

Comment: Seems like you are receiving a parsed result not a string.

Comment: try `alert(result.a);` or  `alert(JSON.stringify(result))`

Comment: you can't display javascript objects in a alert box , better use console.log

Comment: try JSON.stringify instead of parse

Comment: @shakib now it worked.

Comment: `{ '{"type":"type","age":32,"married":false}': '' }` is really strange. This is an object which have a key which is a string representation of a json object... And this key has empty value.

Comment: @Fefux you see something new each day :))

Comment: @Fefux lol, thanks, I got to fix it

Comment: @Fefux I edited the question, the function generated that strange object is shown. How can I create a standard JSon dynamically?

Comment: This is because you make a `JSON.stringify(self.gen_data())`. Just remove it and keep only the part `self.gen_data()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```
alert(result);
```

and receive

```
[object object]
```

when you use `res.json` it set the `content-type` to json so the browser parse it behind the scenes.

so you cant and you dont have to use JSON.parse(...) because the response is already parsed.

Use it as a regular object (think that someone did `JSON.parse(..)`)

Try not use `alert` for this purpose, but use `console.log()`. In the console you can see the object and its properties.

Comment: when sending request, I have to "JSON.stringify(Json-data)" to make it a string. if I send response by "res.json(json-data)", it will come to client as JSon object. is that right?

Comment: @alim yes, because the `content-type` is json it stringify and parse it behind the scenes

Answer (score 3):

First check the type of data like `console.log(typeof result)`, after that if result is object or string then you can handle after it according to your requirement.